# Initializer with c++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, initializer-list

Which is the better way to initialize a type in c++14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int i = 0;
    int _initializer_list_i {0};
    std::cout << "Initialize with = " << std::to_string(i); 
    std::cout << "Initialize with std::initializer_list " << std::to_string(_initializer_list_i);

    std::cout << "\nNormal intialize: \n";
    std::vector<int> v(10, 22);
    for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << "\n";


    std::cout << "\n\nUsing intializer_list: \n";    
    std::vector<int> v2{10, 22};
    for(auto it = v2.begin(); it != v2.end(); it++)
        std::cout << *it << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I use *{}*, it calls the constructor for *std::initializer_list*, but the result is the same as with *=*.  Have some performance case here?

```
int i = 0;
int _initializer_list_i {0};
```

And here's another case using *std::vector<T>*:

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 22);//allocate 10 with value 22
std::vector<int> v2{10, 22}; //Call std::initializer_list with 2 positions{10, 20}
```

Which is the better way to initialize?  Some performance case?

Comment: Those constructors have different effect, how are you going to compare which is better way to initialize? Also, don't try to optimize such things until you definitely know there is a bottleneck there.

Comment: `the result is the same that {operator=}?` The code you show never once uses `operator=`

Comment: "Which is better" is vague without criteria.  Most of your terminology is off -- for example, there is no `operator=` use in the above code.  `int x = 3;` does not involve `operator=`.  Please be more specific in what you mean by "better".

Comment: I was wondering if there is any difference in code quality(design patterns) to initialize with or = std :: initializer_list, or if it's just a matter of preference programmer? it depends of the code?e.g Initialize with {} should be uses in this cases

Answer (score 1):

There will be no performance penalty between operator= and {} init, since, most probably, it will be compiled to same code for int.

Regarding vector - constructor (a,b) is different from initializer list.

Overall, I would recommend you to read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between () and {} initialization is sometimes a bit irritating - in which cases is there a difference, in which cases is it exactly the same bahavior? That's why there exist a couple of very nice articles about this topic: I want to mention just a few:

- Item 7 in Effective modern C++ (Scott Meyers):  Distinguish between () and {} when creating objects.
- GotW #1: [Variable Initialization – or Is It?](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/)
- Andrzej's C++ Blog: [Intuitive interface — Part I](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/intuitive-interface-part-i/)

I personally prefer to use the curly braces {} for array-like initialization only and for constructor calls the round brackets (), but it depends on the specific use-case.